# Receiving yes and no answers in DialogFlow

Tags: api, nlp, dialogflow-es

I am new to DialogFlow. From my default welcome intent, how do I ask a yes or no questions, and you use the reply to get to the next intent?

Comment: what have your tried?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [follow-up intents](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-follow-up-intents). The way it works from the Dialogflow console is the following:

1. Set a question as the [response](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-responses) of your welcome intent.
2. Create an affirmative and/or a negative follow-up intent by clicking "Add follow-up intent" at the desired intent in the intents list. The context is automatically set for you as well as the training phrases. There are no further actions needed from your end to connect one intent with the other.
3. Insert a new question (or a phrase) as the response of this follow-up intent.
4. Repeat steps 2-3 as much times as you desire.

I will illustrate it with an example using also a custom follow-up intent to further the learning experience.

- I have set the question "Are you new to Stack Overflow?" as response text of the welcome intent.
- I have created an affirmative follow-up with response text "Welcome to Stack Overflow!".
- For the negative follow-up I have set the response text "How long you've been a part of stack overflow?"
- Then I created a custom follow-up intent to the negative follow-up intent. In this case you need to train the intent to match the expected answers. I used sentences like "3 years" , "2 months" , ... the wider the range of training sentences the better the intent will behave. This will add a parameter from a system [Date and time entity](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/system-entities#desc)  which we will call "time" that can be [referenced](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-actions-parameters#values) in the response using $time. My response is "I hope you enjoyed the past $time with us.".

So, you can have the following simple conversations:

- Hi! -> Are you new to Stack Overflow?

  - Yes -> Welcome to Stack Overflow!
  - No -> How long you've been a part of stack overflow?

    - 14 months -> I hope you enjoyed the past 14 months with us.

Additionally you can follow the [official quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/build-agent) to quickly build an understanding of how Dialogflow works.